# How to create text with Bulleted lists using pdfkit in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfkit

I have been working since yesterday to generate the report in Pdf format. I have gone through [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit) module. And It seems pretty cool to use. My requirement is list the text with bullet point. I have tried like this

```
     var doc = new PDFDocument();
     doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('userReport.pdf'));
     doc.fillColor("#B22222")
     .fontSize(25)
     .text('Users Count', 250,60)
     .moveDown(0.5);
```

It is creating the text but I want the text with bullet. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

**Simply**, for listing

```
 .list()
```

You may check some samples at

> https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 3):

```
// list params: array, x, y, other params
doc.list([1, 2, 3], 50, 50, {
  // this is how automatic line wrapping will work if the width is specified
  width: 100,
  align: 'left',
  listType: 'bullet',
  bulletRadius: 0.01, // use this value to almost hide the dots/bullets
});
```

This is how it works for me, I hope it helps someone